# ¿Cómo establecer el target a una petición con cURL en php?

Tags: php, formularios, curl, iframe

Normalmente en un formulario, POST por ejemplo establecemos la opción **target** para establecer dónde se debe mostrar la respuesta que se recibe después de enviar el formulario.

```
<form action="ejemplo.php" method="post" target="framename">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<iframe src="" name="framename" id = name="framename" ></iframe>
```

La pregunta es: ¿Si hiciera esta llamada con cURL, cómo podría establecer a *framename* como el target? No he encontrado entre las opciones de la librería, una que sirva para esto. Pero necesito decirle a cURL dónde quiero el resultado.
**Edición: ** Me refiero a la librería cURL de 'PHP':

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//etc....
```

Comment: especificas el tipo como `CURLOPT_POST` y envias a `URL/framename` donde URL es  la url donde te sale el formulario...

Comment: Disculpa, no entiendo. Podrías responder la pregunta, y poner el ejemplo para que sea más claro a qué te refieres, por favor?

Comment: Así como lo tienes, `ejemplo.php` va a realizar la petición por _cURL_ y el resultado debe aparecer en el _iframe_.

Comment: Es en HTML donde defines el _target_, NO puedes hacerlo desde PHP, porque se ejecuta en el servidor, en un contexto completamente diferente. Si necesitas agregar código, por favor edita la pregunta para ponerlo ahí, en comentarios es difícil de interpretar. Además, también explica detalladamente qué es lo que no te funciona o cuál es la duda que tienes.